# How to remove active class from Bootstrap Menu

Tags: html, css

I have created a Bootstrap Menu and place it in a separate header.html file and call that file using php include function in each page of the website. So how can I change the active class depending upon the page that has been loaded.

```
<header class="header_area">
    <div class="main_menu">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="./index.php">
                <img src="./Images/Test Logo Image.png" width="35" height="35" alt="" loading="lazy">
              </a>
            <a class="navbar-brand Company_Text hidden-lg" href="./index.php">Dolphin Rubber Udyog</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <div class="mr-auto"></div>
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="./index.php">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="./about.php">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="./products.php">Products</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="./contact.php">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: You will need to have an idea on what page you are when you load the menu (something like a page_id) and on basis of the page id give the right menu item the active class. You could add a var $page before you include your menu and then use a if statement in your menu.php to determine what menu item wil get the active class

Comment: @NicoShultz actually I just started learning web development so I didn't get what you are really saying can you please tell me the code that I can write. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you requested in the comments you asked for help with the implementation I suggested. I don't have all your code but I think I will be able to help you

For the example I am going to use your about.php and contact.php

It can look something like this

About.php

```
<?php
    $pageName = "about";
    //code to include your menu (include menu.php;)
    //rest of your page code
```

Contact.php

```
<?php
    $pageName = "contact";
    //code to include your menu (include menu.php;)
    //rest of your page code
```

(I am using the shorthand for the if else so your code wont become too long Refrence: https://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples)

Menu.php

```
<header class="header_area">
<div class="main_menu">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="./index.php">
            <img src="./Images/Test Logo Image.png" width="35" height="35" alt="" loading="lazy">
          </a>
        <a class="navbar-brand Company_Text hidden-lg" href="./index.php">Dolphin Rubber Udyog</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <div class="mr-auto"></div>
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link <?php echo ($pageName == 'home') ? "active" : ""; ?>" href="./index.php">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link <?php echo ($pageName == 'about') ? "active" : ""; ?>" href="./about.php">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link <?php echo ($pageName == 'products') ? "active" : ""; ?>" href="./products.php">Products</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link <?php echo ($pageName == 'contact') ? "active" : ""; ?>" href="./contact.php">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
</div>
```

So I'm using the following code to check if the about page should be active

`<?php echo ($pageName == 'about') ? "active" : ""; ?>`

So to summarize what im doing:

I've added a variable to every page `$pageName` that contains a ***unique*** page name.
In menu.php I get that variable (this is possible because `include()` just puts the php code in there and has the variables of the main document)

With that variable I just check if it is equal to the corresponding menu item and if so I add the class `active` to the menu item